# 2 finger swipe in ListView

Tags: android, listview, swipe

How to implement single finger swipe and 2 finger swipe in a ListView? I have implemented single finger swipe using `onTouchListener` in `Adapter`. So I was able to get the position of which item in the ListView was swiped.

Now I want to implement 2 finger swipe. It should be across the entire ListView. Any ideas? Please help.

Comment: http://developingandroid.blogspot.com/2009/09/implementing-swipe-gesture.html

Comment: U gave me code for single finger swipe.. i am asking for 2 finger swipe..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you'll have to implement it by your self (catching all onTouch events: onDown, onMove and onUp).

I suggest you to use some values from [ViewConfiguration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity%28%29) to achieve a natural behavior (requiring the same velocities as one-finger gestures).